# Get unicode by hex string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, hex

Given a hex code, for example: `1f60d`, how do I find the corresponding unicode (code point) ?

Answer (score 7):

Convert the string to an integer (e.g. via [`hex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-hex)) and the integer to a character via [`chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
'1f60d'.hex.chr('UTF-8')
#=> ""
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do that by using [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-pack):

`["1F60d".to_i(16)].pack("U*")`

Comment: So, you knew the answer at the time of asking this question!!

Comment: @JagdeepSingh SO [explicitly encourages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) posting questions with answers for the sake of knowledge base quality improvement.

Comment: Yeah, I have no issue with that. Was just confirming. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\u{HEX}` to accomplish the same.

```
puts "\u{1F60d}"
```

Comment: It won’t work with dynamic strings.

Comment: IMO it's useful to know yet another syntax for this. Upvoted.